# How can I iterate in a list with sepration of them?

Tags: python

I want to say

> for f in x: do certain thing.

but i dont want to connect them to each other.
first do a work for x[0] then for x[1] then etc.

```
x = ['ABCED', 'BACF', 'BCD']
```

for exmple, it cant seprate them by the index, it just repeate print part for all q in x.
how can i fix it?

```
  for f in x:
        for q in f:
            print('hi')
```

the output that i except that is:

> [[A,B,C,E,D],[B,A,C,F],[B,C,D]]

Comment: What output you are expecting?

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list` on `str` create a list of each character:

```
out = [list(i) for i in x]
print(out)

# Output
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'D'], ['B', 'A', 'C', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'D']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ['ABCED', 'BACF', 'BCD']
new_list= [list(i) for i in x]
```

or:

```
list(map(list, x))
```

output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'D'], ['B', 'A', 'C', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'D']]
```

Comment: No i want to have this output:
[[A,B,C,E,D],[B,A,C,F],[B,C,D]]

Comment: what output do you want? @MahsaAbarghani

Comment: [[A,B,C,E,D],[B,A,C,F],[B,C,D]] @TalFolkman